# how to read last line from binary file

Tags: c++, file-io, binary

There’s a binary file which has data like this (both of these has string datatype);

```
Tyler   Bred
Guus    Hiddink
Didier  Droggba
```

I want to read data located at the end of the file (exactly it is Didier & Droggba in this case). So I wrote a code to handle it as follows;

Structure:

```
struct user
{
   string id;
   string pwd;
};
```

Code to read data:

```
void confirm(const char* f)
{
    user u;
    ifstream in;
    in.open(f, ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!in)
    {
        cout << "failed to read file!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    while (in >> u.id >> u.pwd)
    {
       if (in.eof())
       {
           cout << "Registration Complete. " << endl;
           cout << "Your user information:  " << endl;
           cout << "ID:" << u.id << " " << "Password: " << u.pwd << endl;
       }
    }
}
```

I run the above code but it didn’t work. I've got nothing.
So I changed a code like this;

```
void confirm(const char* f,user* u)
{
    user u1;
    ifstream in;
    in.open(f, ios::in | ios::binary);

    while (in >> u1.id >> u1.pwd)
    {
        if (!in)
        {
            cout << "failed to open file" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }

        if((u1.id == u->id)&& (u1.pwd == u->pwd))
        {
            cout << "Registration Complete." << endl;
            cout << "You registered;" << endl;
            cout << "ID:" << u1.id << "," << "Pwd: " << u1.pwd << endl;
        }
        delete u;
    }
}
```

unfortunately this didn't work. I've got "access violation ..." error message.

I tried many other codes to solve the problem but these things didn’t work, too. I think the problem is: if (in.eof())
But I don’t know how I should change it to solve the problem.
If somebody point out my fault or give me a tip, I’d appreciate it very much.

Comment: Lines have no meaning in binary. Your question makes no sense in current form. You should invent your file format conventions instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's normally a newline character (or character***s*** on some operating systems), at the end of each line in a file.  Your code...

```
while (in >> u.id >> u.pwd)
{
   if (in.eof())
   {
       cout << "Registration Complete. " << endl;
       cout << "Your user information:  " << endl;
       cout << "ID:" << u.id << " " << "Password: " << u.pwd << endl;
   }
}
```

Assumes you'll hit `eof` after reading the last person's name, but when you read that last name, if the line has a newline you'll not yet have hit `eof()`, then the next `while (in >>...` test will fail and skip the `while`-loop body, never entering the `if (in.eof())`.

The smallest change you can make to fix your code:

```
while (in >> u.id >> u.pwd >> std::skipws)
{
   if (in.eof())
   {
       cout << "Registration Complete. " << endl;
       cout << "Your user information:  " << endl;
       cout << "ID:" << u.id << " " << "Password: " << u.pwd << endl;
   }
}
```

The `>> std::skipws` will advance to either the end of file or the next name, setting the `eof()` flag as you hoped.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be something like this:

```
void confirm(const char* f)
{
    user u;
    ifstream in(f, ios::in | ios::binary);

    while (in >> u.id >> u.pwd)
        ;

    cout << "Registration Complete.\n";
    cout << "Your user information:\n";
    cout << "ID:" << u.id << " " << "Password: " << u.pwd << "\n";
}
```

If I were doing it, however, I'd define an `operator>>` for a `user` struct, something like this:

```
struct user {
    std::string id;
    std::string pwd;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, user &u) { 
        return is >> u.id >> u.pwd;
    }
};
```

This simplifies the main code a bit, to something like this:

```
user u;

while (in >> u)
    ;
```

Admittedly, in this case (only two fields) that's only a minor improvement, but it's a small improvement nonetheless, and when you have more fields to deal with (and especially when code to read an object gets more complex) isolating the code to read an object into its own function can simplify the rest of the code quite a bit.

Note that this works regardless of how much or little white-space is in the file following the last data (trailing \n or lack thereof doesn't affect the result).

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea17d14f9bf651fb)

Comment: That `while (in >> u.id >> u.pwd) ;` is guaranteed ***not*** to touch `u`'s fields if already at `eof` is a nice, simplifying guarantee in recent C++ Standards, and it's interesting to note the contrast with your custom operator's `return is >> u.id >> u.pwd;`, for which `u.id` may succeed and modify `u.id` only to have `u.pwd` fail for a corrupt input file containing an odd number of strings to extract: you'd print out the last string as if it were `u.id` and the previous as `u.pwd`, (my answer would print nothing :-( ).  For correct error handling: Basile's `getline`/`istringstream` is good.

Answer (score 1):

Lines do not really exist in binary files, except as a *convention*, like a line is a sequence of bytes (all different from `'\0'` and from `'\n'`) terminated by a newline `'\n'` (and that convention might differ from one operating system to the next one, some OSes using `"\r\n"` or `"\n\r"` or even `'\r'` as line end).

You could loop on reading lines with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) till end of file, keep the line in some `std::string` and parse the last line string (using [std::istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), [sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf), etc...)

Alternatively, consider the end of line as a space separator, as [Tony D'answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34626337/841108) suggests. Then a *single* line with `Tyler Bred John Doe` will be handled as two lines `Tyler Bred` and `John Doe`.

Answer (score 0):

`delete u`

This will free the memory associated with the `user` structure. If there are more than 1 lines in the file you will get an access violation since in the next iteration you will again touch the memory associated with `user` structure.

Also this:

```
in.open(f, ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!in)
    {
        cout << "failed to read file!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
```

was the correct way to test whether the file was opened successfully or not. 
Additionally you also need to handle the newline character in each read.

I am assuming you want to bail out after you find out the first match. You should modify your code like this:

```
if((u1.id == u->id)&& (u1.pwd == u->pwd))
{
     cout << "Registration Complete." << endl;
     cout << "You registered;" << endl;
     cout << "ID:" << u1.id << "," << "Pwd: " << u1.pwd << endl;
     delete u;
     break;
}
```

Although I do not like this pattern where the callee is taking the responsibility of freeing the memory. I suggest let the caller decide what to do with the memory passed in the `user` structure.
As an additional suggestion using debugger may help you for diagnosing such issues.